# Why would a settlement set up shop INSIDE a supermassive creature's mouth?

Tags: creature-design, society, humans, cities

In a story idea I have, there is a massive, stationary beast, with teeth the size of houses, a body as large as a continent, and an unfathomably large mouth (don't ask how it sustains itself, nobody knows or cares) Common sense dictates that humans would avoid this thing at all costs.

And yet, there are humans living INSIDE this thing's mouth. Enough to form a sizeable settlement, in fact. It would likely strike an outside observer as utterly insane; after all, living in some massive beastie's mouth is the very definition of living dangerously, as there is always the risk of being swallowed and digested looming over you. Plus, spending your life inside a wet, warm mouth seems rather unappealing.

All this raises the question: **Why would these humans be living in the mouth of this thing?!**

Comment: Teeth the size of houses, relative to a body the size of a continent? That would be like a person having teeth so small that a thousand of them could be packed inside a single skin cell.

Comment: @SolomonSlow A human tooth is around 9 mm. This thing is 2.5 million times larger than a human. Its teeth should be 22,500 meters tall, or 22.5 kilometers. Close to three times taller than Everest. Perhaps the settlers use the teeth, and the relatively narrow passageways between them, to defend their kingdom. No invading army can scale a near-vertical 22km wall.

Answer (score 6):

> Common sense dictates that humans would avoid this thing at all costs.

Humans build houses and settlements on the side of active volcanoes, on shores subjected to tsunami or flooding, in territories subject to earthquakes or plagued by endemic illnesses or other risks.

There is no absolute scale, every decision on where to settle is based on a trade off. Unless the creature chews every 5 minutes, it's possible that some people will decide that settling in the mouth is worth the effort and the risk.

It can be that this creature, while eating, gets food remains between its teeth, these remains be valuable ores, or that its mouth secrets something valuable for the humans, which harvest and sell it for a profit.

Comment: A nice start, though my question is WHY the people would conclude that settling in the mouth is worth the risk and effort.

Comment: @Brinstar77 I believe the main point of the answer is to highlight that "inside the mouth" doesn't actually impose a particularly novel condition. "Why would they settle in a mouth" is basically identical to the question of why people would settle _anywhere_. You could pick any of the hundred of reasons why people have settled in any particular location and use that. You just need to make sure that the benefit is greater than the cost, which can be pretty darn low if "well, it hasn't eaten us yet" is a reasonable response from the inhabitants.

Answer (score 6):

If these humans are in a situation where the life outside of the creature's mouth is even worse, then it makes complete sense for them to live like this.

It sounds like there are some advantages to this setup. Humans living inside are protected from weather extremes and from any dangerous predators. If they can't grow/hunt their own food then it's a problem. Then again, this creature must consume such a gigantic amount of food that feeding off of bits of food stuck between the teeth could provide all the food this settlement needs. Lack of building/crafting materials could also be a problem but this creature probably swallows entire trees and rocks accidentally.

Actually this sounds like this could be a symbiotic relationship. The human settlement strips out bits of food that could be hard for the creature to digest and uses it for building/crafting and in return they get safety and a steady supply of food. Lack of sunlight and fresh air would still be a problem, but again depending on what life is like outside this could still be preferable for these people.

Comment: There are issues with your answer, but largely because I accidentally left out a pretty important bit of info: the creature is STATIONARY, and thus isn't going to be eating much food or trees/rocks. Sorry.

Comment: It's possible for a stationary or mostly stationary creature to feed itself, e.g. [sea anemone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_anemone) - there are probably much better examples. If the creature doesn't feed itself, then how does it sustain its life? Is it magical?

Comment: Who knows? The only things it could eat would be the animal who occasionally tumbles into its stomach, and possibly the humans living in its mouth. How has it survived like this is the purview of a different question.

Answer (score 6):

## Mouth? No. It's a cave, right?

Your creature doesn't move, doesn't obviously consume food, and if it gets water, it's because it siphons off of a river (which might constitute a food source...). Something this passive doesn't have much active metabolism, so are the settlers really so sure this thing is alive? Maybe they think it's a cave. Maybe it is a ridiculously huge corpse. Either way, there isn't much danger. Maybe this is a giant fungus, or plant, or sponge-like creature, and calling this chasm a mouth sounds ridiculous since it doesn't obviously eat. It might, for all intents and purposes be a giant nook in a tree. People live in trees when it suits them.

Any advantage of living there (shelter, nutrients, security, warmth, etc.) would be enough to make the creature's mouth desirable. If you don't believe the thing is alive, or that it's completely immobilized and harmless, then WHY NOT?

Answer (score 2):

Think valuables and resources. Remember, [ambergris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambergris) is a valuable perfume additive that is formed in the digestive tract of sperm whales, and [kopi luwak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopi_luwak) is an expensive coffee bean that must be partially digested and excreted by civets. Perhaps something this creature produces, secretes, excretes, regurgitates, etc has human use: strong and light organic construction materials, medicines or intoxicants, unique crystals mined from its teeth for jewelry or technology, etc, etc. People will live just about anywhere if living there gives them a killing in the market.

Answer (score 0):

**Rain:**
These people like to stay dry. The height of the cave must be at least several miles high. A settlement inside the mouth would be protected from bad weather while still getting enough sunlight to see, unlike a traditional cave where the opening is too shallow for significant light to pass through, not to mention far too small for a settlement.
If the weather in the region is particularly severe, perhaps this is the only place that poor people, who can't afford sturdier stone homes, can build their shacks.

**Heat:**
The creature might be maintaining an internal body temp of some temperature, perhaps a reasonable hibernating 60 degrees. The body temp of the beast prevents winter temperatures from occurring within its body-- it's always t-shirt weather in the body of the beast!
I would live in the place where I don't freeze to death in the winter.

**Food?**
If the creature is an animal and edible, maybe it's a free supply of fresh meat for these settlers. Come dinner time, they head outside with a carving knife and collect dinner.

Comment: "The people like to stay dry." And what better way to do that than climb into a wet, moist, saliva-filled mouth?

Comment: @Brinstar77, I assume that the creature wouldn't be actively salivating. If it's salivating, it's probably active enough to have a fully active immune system. If every part of the creature is scaled up accordingly, the creature would be about 2.5 million times larger than a human (in every direction). A white blood cell is around 15 micrometers. 15 micrometers *2.5 million = 36 meters! This thing's immune defence "cells" would be the size of a monster! And it's one goal would be wiping out the human settlement. Uh oh.

Answer (score 0):

Well isn't this interesting.
The "why" of the question reminds me of the iconic response from Alastor of "Hazbin Hotel" to being asked "why does anyone do anything?": *sheer, absolute boredom!*

Obviously no one would decide to live inside some gargantuan creature's mouth just for the kick of it, but jokes aside:
In a fantasy setting there could be a ton of different reasons for why people would go on creating a similar dwelling.
I was thinking of something like this - this thing is the size of a continent you said. Well, what if the people residing there were being hunted or threatened by some sort of creatures or civilization from a neighbouring continent and it so happens that said threatening force is deadly afraid of this continent like-creature?
I mean, everyone would be. But let's suppose this runaway people took the saying "keep your friends close and your enemies closer" to a whole new level and decided to go live directly inside something that terrifies their adversaries more than anything else?
At least they would be sure they wouldn't be attacked anymore.

We could also add that this creature lives with his mouth open and like you said, doesn't move. There would be no problem with the oxygen or light. The food depends on what creatures are present in this world and if any of them would go inside the mouth.
Another point in favour of living there would be that this beast only attacks/reacts negatively to the presence of specific beings: among them the same ones that threaten the people who decided to go live inside the mouth. This would be perfect: for the majority of the time this thing is immobile, mouth open, maybe it only feeds off of some particles present in the air together with who or whatever happens to tumble down its throat, I don't know. It basically stays in a near constant state of sleep until it senses its enemies coming near. Then it goes berserk and is capable of annihilating anything.

If I were part of those people who decided to live there and these were the premises I honestly would think it a good choice.
10/10 would recommend XD.

Answer (score 0):

**Potion Seller**

[image]

There is not much of a market for potions these days. But if a single adventurer comes by you can make it big selling them 200 red potions and 400 green potions. Adventurers have lots of moolah you see, from slaughtering exotic and endangered fauna.

Unfortunately adventurers are few and far between. Fortunately many of the most popular quest routes take you inside the beast and out through the other end. Often they are searching for rare ingredients that can only be found in the depth of the beast. Or else they are looking for princesses of neighboring kingdoms who so carelessly fell into the pit while out admiring the sunset.

Whatever their motives,  those guys need potions. And they need them yesterday. And it's a good thing you came to us.

Answer (score 0):

### Your humans are just like giant bacterias...

We have to remember that mouths are [host to hundreds if not thousands of microspecies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_microbiology). And, as far as I know, we don't kill all of them just by closing it! In fact, we never reach a clean mouth even after making your toothbrushing.

Remember that teeth are sized against a specific prey, you don't have to worry if they're in the ten or hundred of meters. Indeed, the space between them would allow anyone to move in and out freely. You'd need to stand on top of them to risk something (and even then!).

### ... And the immune system doesn't deal well with humans

Your humans are smart, your humans are clever, and they are greedy. In fact, among the species that decides to live in the mouth, humans are the ones that are digging holes in the teeth. In toothcare, it's well known that once a carie started to set in, the body is unable to get rid of it, external help is needed. And humans are just the perfect candidate for that : They drill a house and craft dentin solid tools. And... Also precious necklaces to sell out as the "legendary creatinent ivory lucky charms", too. There's nothing to stop 'em poaching there.

Moreover, like you often see giant creatures being slower than mice , your giant creature has a very slow metabolism : Any movement is extremely slow, Breathing is done over weeks (lowering drastically the wind speed), and saliva's flowing like rivers that move over time, leaving sometimes puddles here and there. Nothing you cannot deal with. At most you have to worry about the yearly cough, which takes the shape of a storm for 3 days. And heat is only hitting up if you dig straight down into a blood vessel; There's so much distance to them that most of the heat dissipates before it reaches the surface, leaving only a warm, cozy carpet to lie on.

Really, it's a very nice place to live there! Weird sure, but nice!